# How can I prepopulate certain properties in a model before a method is executed within a Controller

Tags: c#, .net-core, controller, middleware

I have multiple input models, and the majority of them include 'OwnerId' and 'CreatedBy' properties. I am seeking a mechanism to automatically populate these properties with default values. I attempted to use middleware, but I encountered difficulties in locating the mentioned properties to populate them.

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<bool> ExportPackingListProductBulkInsert(PackingListProductFromSalePermitInput input)
{
    // input.OwnerId = 10;
    // input.CreatedBy = get current date
    // Inserting process
    return await true;
}
```

I have a substantial number of `Actions` where their inputs need to be populated before the Action is executed. Is there a mechanism to automatically populate these inputs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could inherit from `ActionFilterAttribute` and tag your API method. Then, override `OnActionExecuting` method on this attribute.

`OnActionExecuting` is called right before entering the tagged API method.

You can access method arguments via `ActionExecutingContext.ActionArguments` which is a `Dictionary<string, object>` object. Its key is the argument name, here "input". You will need to cast the value to the right type, ie `PackingListProductFromSalePermitInput` or one of its base classes.

Something like this:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)]
public class FillAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{

    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext pContext)
    {
        var found = pContext.ActionArguments.TryGetValue("input", out var argument);

        if (found && argument is PackingListProductFromSalePermitInput input)
        {
            input.OwnerId = 10;
            input.CreatedBy = DateTime.UtcNow;//get current date
        }

        base.OnActionExecuting(pContext);
    }
}
```

For your API method:

```
[HttpPost]
[Fill]
public async Task<bool> ExportPackingListProductBulkInsert(PackingListProductFromSalePermitInput input)
{
    // Inserting process
    return await true;
}
```

You can also inherit from `IObjectModelValidator` and add it as middleware in `ConfigureServices` method

```
.ConfigureServices(services =>
{
   services.AddSingleton<IObjectModelValidator, FillValidator>();
}
```

You would not have to tag every API method in this case, but it will be called for every endpoint.

```
public class FillValidator : IObjectModelValidator
{
    public void Validate(ActionContext pActionContext, ValidationStateDictionary? pValidationState, string pPrefix, object? pModel)
    {
        if(pModel is PackingListProductFromSalePermitInput input)
        {
            input.OwnerId = 10;
            input.CreatedBy = DateTime.UtcNow;//get current date
        }
    }
}
```

The third option, and certainly the easiest, is to fill in the properties in the object's constructor. But I'm sure you already are aware of this :)

**EDIT**

In order to use IObjectModelValidator efficiently with many models, you could use polymorphism this way

```
public class BaseModel
{
    public virtual void Fill() 
    {
    }
}


public class PackingListProductFromSalePermitInput : BaseModel
{
    public override void Fill()
    {
        this.OwnerId = 10;
        this.CreatedBy = DateTime.UtcNow;//get current date
    }
}

public class OtherModel : BaseModel
{
    public override void Fill()
    {
        //TODO fill in what you want
    }
}

public class FillValidator : IObjectModelValidator
{
    public void Validate(ActionContext pActionContext, ValidationStateDictionary? pValidationState, string pPrefix, object? pModel)
    {
        if(pModel is BaseModel model)
        {
            model.Fill();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your suggestion is indeed helpful. However, the issue is that this solution only works with the `PackingListProductFromSalePermitInput` model and cannot be applied to other models. Is there any way to modify the code so that it can work with all models?

Comment: Either you have a common base class, and can cast to this particular base class to fill in properties, either you will end up with a list of cast for each model.

Comment: If each model inherits from `BaseModel` but has various properties to fill in you could add a `Fill` method in your base class that you override for each model. I think it's a clean solution, using polymorphism.

Comment: In the first solution `found = pContext.ActionArguments.TryGetValue("input", out var argument);` if someone change the `input` name in actions this part of code won't be run. Is there any way to prevent this changes? For example, finding the model in body of context or something.

Comment: Instead of searching by key, you could iterate the collection of values and try to cast to your model, yes. This would be more robust in case the variable name is changed.